# Annexure usage in Writing

Tags: american-english, subcontinental-english

I have been seeing the use of *Annexure* and *Appendix* for quite a while. My understanding of *Appendix* is that it's the information the writer forgot or discovered after writing about a topic and using appendix they can write those for the reader.

I am not hundred percent clear about *Annexure* though, why one would want to use *annexure*?

Comment: I've not come across ***annexure*** before, and I can't imagine a context where I might consider using it instead of ***annexation*** (or at a pinch, ***annexment***). My advice would be to forget the word completely (as I'm sure I will! :)

Comment: ...as you can see from [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=annexation%2Cannexure%2Cannexment&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cannexation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cannexure%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cannexment%3B%2Cc0), ***annexure*** only seemed to have very brief currency just after WW2, which suggests it might have had some "niche" use among politicians. Similar to ***subsidiarity***, which nearly always refers to some opaque aspect of EU "legislative scope" that no-one is expected to understand anyway.

Comment: My father sent a Tax related document today and it had Annexure in it, so it is used in the documents today too. :)

Comment: Your profile doesn't specify "location" for you (or your father), but I'm guessing it's India. I don't think ***annexure = appendix*** (to a body of text) was ever common in mainstream Anglophone cultures, and I note the most recent cite in the full OED is well over a century old. You'd probably need to ask a few Indians why they preserved / resurrected this unusual usage.

Comment: The understanding of *appendix* presented in this question is odd. The appendix isn't post-process material, but rather material that has been excluded from the text because it is less integral to the text itself. Far from the author forgetting it, they are making a deliberate decision to include it in a separate section. Additional data, explanations of formulas or methods, and similar material goes in an appendix.

Comment: 'Annexure' is totally unused in American books. Though it may be common practice where you're from, it looks really strange in the US.

Comment: I must agree with all those comments who say "never heard of it", but I have heard the word "_annex_" used to refer to subsidiary documentation. I believe this was a legal usage. Something like "A full list of items covered by this legislation can be found in _annex_ 3". Why they didn't use "appendix" I'll never know.

Answer (score 2):

Annexure is a common Indian-English word describing supplement or appendix to a document. (usually: legal, taxation, proposals, technical reports etc.)

You may want to use annexure when you are referring to the detailed part of the document. "For detailed 5-yr tax assessment worksheet, please refer to Annexure..."

Oxford Dictionary: [annexure](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/annexure)

PS// One can use *addendum* to describe additional materials or afterthought.